# Variables not working as expected within function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, numpy, variables

I'm trying to build a sort of numerical derivation function. I want to build a function to do so, however I'm getting some unusual behavior that I've not encountered before. I pass an array`w` into my function and define new variables from it, say `w_new`. The problem is that when I manipulate w_new I also make changes to `w`. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Here is my minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np

eps = 0.05 #doesnt matter
i = 0 #doesnt matter
weight = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float)

def func(eps, w, i):

    w_min = w
    w_min[i] = w_min[i] - eps
    print('w_min:', w_min)
    print('w:', w)

    w_max = w
    w_max[i] = w_max[i] + eps
    print('w:', w)
    print('w_max:', w_max)
    print('w_min', w_min)

    return [w_min, w_max, w]
```

When I run this in a console I get

```
func(eps, wgt, i)
('w_min:', [0.95, 1.1, 1.2])
('w:', [0.95, 1.1, 1.2])
('w:', [1.0, 1.1, 1.2])
('w_max:', [1.0, 1.1, 1.2])
('w_min', [1.0, 1.1, 1.2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that python will pass any iterable (or object instance for that matter) by reference to the function. This means that if you have some function f(x) that manipulate x directly, then the variable you fed into f will also be modified.

This is done because you might want to have a function f that takes a large list as input, however, copying this list before feeding it into the function will take a fair bit of time to do. Therefore the list is sent into the function without being copied first.

There are two workarounds for this, the first (and most often preferred) is simply to not change x inside f. The second option is to define a function this way.

```
from copy import copy
def f(x_list):
    x_list = copy(x_list)
    # some code that manipulate x_list
```

Finally, I'll just add a warning for something called the mutable default trap that happens if you have a mutable default argument in python. Here's a great post about that: https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/

Comment: Thank you! It's hard to believe I've not run into this issue before now.

Comment: Array has a copy method, `wmin=w.copy()`